# How do I find total sales in my table on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Attempting to count total number of sales per month what table shows what day EACH sale happened.

My code is as follows:

```
WITH sales_months AS (
  SELECT
  '2018-01-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-01-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-02-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-02-28' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-03-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-03-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-04-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-04-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-05-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-05-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-06-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-06-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-07-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-07-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-08-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-08-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-09-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-09-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-10-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-10-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-11-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-11-31' AS last_day
UNION
  SELECT
  '2018-12-01' AS first_day,
  '2018-12-31' AS last_day
)
cross_join AS (
SELECT *
FROM sales_2018
CROSS JOIN sales_months
),
purchase AS (
SELECT GlobalCustomerID, first_day AS sales_month,
CASE 
    WHEN (SoldDate BETWEEN first_day AND last_day)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS purchased
FROM cross_join
),
purchase_total AS (
SELECT
  month,
  sum(purchased)
FROM purchase
GROUP BY month;
```

It returns an error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross_join AS ( SELECT * FROM sales_2018 CROSS JOIN sales_months ), purchase AS ' at line 50

I believe it may be a problem with how I'm formatting my dates?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Or MySQL? You've tagged both, but they are quite different RDBMS.

Comment: Your a missing a comma to end the preceding CTE.

Comment: Error states MySQL.    Year(salesdate), month(salesdate) , sum(sales) from salestable group by 1,2 is the easy method here.  The union method you have here (you need to inner join on a date range) will preserve months with zero sales...otherwise it's unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share more of what your table structure looks like? If you want the sum of sales by month, you really shouldn't need to identify the first/last of each month (especially not manually). Something like this would be more straight forward, but I'm not sure of your schema so it may require tweaking.

```
SELECT 
      YEAR(SoldDate)
    , MONTH(SoldDate)
    , COUNT(GlobalCustomerID)
FROM sales_2018
GROUP BY YEAR(SoldDate), MONTH(SoldDate)
```